# Custom `password_reset_confirm.html` template won't redirect to `password_reset_complete` view

Tags: django

I made a custom `password_reset_confirm.html` template. But when a user enters a new password and hits submit, the browser does not redirect to the admin view `password_reset_complete`.

Here's the form I made in the custom `password_reset_confirm.html` template:

```
  <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">   
    <form id="reset-pw-confirm-form" name="newPWForm" method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input 
            id="id_new_password1"
            type="[[[ newPW.showPW ? 'text' : 'password' ]]]"
            name="new_password1"
            ng-model="newPW.pw"
            ng-minlength="8" 
            ng-maxlength="32"
        required>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-disabled="!newPW.pw">Submit</button>
        <input 
            id="id_new_password2"
            type="hidden"
            value="[[[ newPW ]]]"
            name="new_password2"
            ng-model="newPW"
            ng-minlength="8" 
            ng-maxlength="32"                       
            required>
    </form>
</div>
```

When I fill out the password and hit submit, the browser sends a POST request to the same URL it landed on, but the page seems to just refresh with nothing changed. The user's password remains unchanged. It seems Django's `auth/views.py` did not execute properly.

In that view, there's this code:

```
if post_reset_redirect is None:
    post_reset_redirect = reverse('password_reset_complete')
else:
    post_reset_redirect = resolve_url(post_reset_redirect)
```

When I have the view print `post_reset_redirect`, it prints `None`. Could this be the issue?

How can I make my custom template compatible with Django's `password_reset_confirm` view?

Comment: I don't understand the point of the Angular code here.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Do you mean the JS? I thought it was required...

Comment: Required for what? What is it actually doing?

Comment: I thought it was needed for the HTML part of it to work.

Comment: Well, no. The original template doesn't have any JS, does it?

Comment: I don't need the JS file for the Angular to work that's in the HTML tag attributes?

Comment: Err, of course you would do. But I asked you what the Angular was for and you didn't seem to know. Why exactly do you have Angular in this template at all?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delayed reply. The purpose of the Angular is to show the user one password `input`. They type their new password once instead of having to do it twice. The visible `input` and the hidden one have the same Angular model, so when the user types their new password into the visible `input`, it automatically fills the other one. So when the user submits, the password and the hidden "confirmation" gets sent to Django. At least, that's how I was hoping it would work.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Removed JS since I realize now it was not needed

Comment: The most likely issue is that your form isn't actually validating. Have you checked that the two password fields being sent to the server are actually identical?

Comment: I believe this is the second time you are posting a bounty on this? You should include a minimal git repo to get it done this time. Would give you a higher chance of a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My hidden `input`'s `value` and `ng-model` attributes needed to be set to `newPW.pw`.

Answer (score 0):

When you specifies "action" attribute for the form it will be used as your link for data sending so probably your logic isn't handled. Try to remove it and check you js files that the data is sent to the the specified link. 
Also please check all required parameters for the password_reset_confirm
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/views/